# How Java verifies request against WSDL?

Tags: java, wsdl

I'm learning Java Web Services with SOAP (XML) and I succeeded in putting in place a simple web service that works like a charm.

I do understand that now I have an entry point where a SOAP client can make requests.

But, I cannot understand which mechanism verifies agains the WSDL that the incoming request is correct ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the SOAP framework you are using.
For example if you are using [CXF](https://cxf.apache.org) you can enable validation like this:

```
<jaxws:endpoint name="{http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http}SoapPort"
    wsdlLocation="wsdl/hello_world.wsdl"
    createdFromAPI="true">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

See: https://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIturnonschemavalidationforjaxwsendpoint?

Comment: For JAX-WS there is an `@SchemaValidation` anntotation which enabled request validation according to the WSDL/XSD.

Comment: See: https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-20-fcs/arch/com/sun/xml/ws/developer/SchemaValidation.html